# Baked vs realtime global illumination in unity

Tags: unity, realtime, lightmap, global-illumination

I use unity. So far I know that the baked GI is less GPU processing when the game is played so if possible, I need to use baked GI.

Newbie question: I'm using unity and just curious in the light setting, is there any situation or in what condition that we can turn on both realtime and baked GI at the same time?  Or is it only practical to turn on one of them?

Comment: Realtime global illumination with Enlighten is deprecated and will soon be removed, [according to the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-window.html). So I wouldn't recommend it for a new project. [It's planned to be replaced in 2021.1](https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/07/03/enlighten-will-be-replaced-with-a-robust-solution-for-baked-and-real-time-giobal-illumination/). So it might be safest to stick to baked illumination for now until the new solution is stabilized.

Comment: Presumably though you started by searching for your question, and found [these existing threads](https://forum.unity.com/threads/when-to-use-baked-gi-when-to-use-rtgi-and-when-to-use-mixed-lighting.526273/) addressing [exactly this topic](https://medium.com/@JasonTuttle/real-time-gi-vs-baked-for-mobile-games-ef173929d8cb)? Is there anything in there that you need help applying to your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the setting "Realtime Global Illumination" in the [Unity Lighting Window](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/lighting-window.html) is deprecated. It only applies to the legacy rendering pipeline. It has no effect on the new scriptable render pipelines (URP, HDRP or a custom one).

Here is an example scene rendered with the build-in pipeline. The two lights are identical except that the left one is baked and the right one is real-time.

Here is the scene with Baked GI on and Realtime GI off:

[image: Baked_only]

As you can see, there are notable differences. The right one generates a specular highlight on the sphere in the center while the left one doesn't. Also note that the walls, ceiling and floor on the left side is slightly brighter. This is because GI simulates indirect light which bounces off of bright surfaces.

Here is the same scene, but with Realtime Global Illumination on but Baked Global Illumination off:

[image: realtime_only]

Now both lights are simulated in real-time, so they look identical. The whole scene is slightly brighter because both lights generate light bounces.

Now when you enable both systems at the same time you get this:

[image: Both on]

A much brighter image which has the differences caused by combining realtime and baked lights in a baked scene. Apparently Unity adds the light from both systems. So you got the cost of both systems and the disadvantages of both systems.

So no, you should not do this.